# Magento 2 Stable Version

Tags: magento2, development

I have a doubt on Magento2 as we can see it is rising up and themes started coming up of magento version 2.

But i have a confusion of whether it is stable to use in development projects, or it is currently not recommended for development projects.

Like it may have bugs that are sill need to get fixed, i want to confirm that can i start using it for my clients.

I am talking about Magento2 CE.

Comment: Okay thanx for the prompt reply @rohit :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento have  *latest stable C.E 2.x version  2.0.2.*

From my point of view,magento ***2.X version better for client if your client
requirement***

- almost same as  2.X default  feature and theme
- have minor customization

But if you lot of ***customization then go with  magento 1.x version because of*** :

- Lot of Extension
- enough expertize.
- Lot of themes
- Development reference

**This is as per as my thought**